# two-parameter Pareto distribution with known A

Tags: self-study, bayesian, pareto-distribution

I am trying to solve the following problem. Any help would be great:

Scores are distributed as a two-parameter Pareto distribution with a=3
Scores for 3 groups are as follows:

Group A has expected value of 4, prior .10
Group B has expected value of 7, prior .70
Group C has expected value of 10, prior .20

If a person has a score of 13.1, what is the posterior prob that they are in group C?

Comment: Could you please explain what "$a=3$" means?  Are you perhaps referring to the minimum possible value of the distribution?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but in the problem, it states that scores are distributed as a two-parameter Pareto distribution with a=3. They don't give me theta...
Next, all I have are the three groups with values and weighing...